# Gradle: Could not download artifact 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.0.0-mr1:hadoop-core.jar'

Tags: maven, hadoop, gradle, artifact

I have the following entries in my gradle file:

```
repositories {
   maven {
    url "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
   }
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0')
}
```

When running ./gradlew build, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.

> Could not download artifact 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.0.0-mr1:hadoop-core.jar'
>   Artifact 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:2.0.0-mr1:hadoop-core.jar' not found.

What am I missing? I can see the repo at https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0/

Comment: Resolves just fine for me with Gradle 2.0, except that you might have to add in `mavenCentral()` because `cloudera-repos` may not have all transitive dependencies. The error looks more as if a different (possibly faulty) dependency declaration caused the problem. Or perhaps the problem only exists in an older Gradle version.